# SSRS Moving average

Tags: reporting-services

Please i need help to calculate moving average in SSRS. see example from excel bellow. i have search net and looked at other forum without success.

the moving average is something like Avg(A1:A3),Avg(A2:A4),Avg(A3:A5)etc

```
Count of ID     BAND                
        -20 >20 <12 Grand Total Three Months Avg
Year       Month    <15   15-20  >20   Total
2012/2013   Jan     35    9      13     57    57
            Feb     34    23     20     77    67
            Mar     25    33     8      66   =AVERAGE(F5:F7)
            Apr      7    31     13     51    65
            May      6    10     13     29    49
            Jun     19    14     18     51    44
            Jul     34    16     6      56    45
            Aug     26    21     30     77   =AVERAGE(F10:F12)
            Sep     13    53     21          =AVERAGE(F11:F13)
            Oct     1     34     33     68   =AVERAGE(F12:F14)
            Nov     35    16     19     70    53
            Dec     33    23     36     92    77
```

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far besides looking online? 2. Also can you fix your question as first couple of lines are not clear what you copied and pasted from excel.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal - thanks for formatting the data - it helps understand what the issue is. Why do people ask **What have you tried so far?** I don't see what difference it makes and this is actually a difficult issue that most users would have no idea where to start.

Comment: Is editing the underlying dataset an option? It strikes me this would be easier to perform in SQL than from SSRS